# Getting undefined method `to_sym' from FactoryGirl create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have a simple spec:

```
describe Setting do
  subject { create(:setting) }
  it { should be_valid }
end
```

with the factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :setting do
    key "some_key"
    value "The appropriate value"
  end 
end
```

When I run the spec:

```
rake spec SPEC=spec/models/setting_spec.rb
```

I get the following error:

```
1) Setting should be valid                                                                                              
 Failure/Error: it { should be_valid }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
 # ./spec/models/setting_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I tried using a let(:setting) in place of the subject line and got the same error.

EDIT Per comments:

The error refers to the line `it { should be_valid }`

The model is:

```
class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :key, :value
  validates_uniqueness_of :key
end
```

Here's the trace:

```
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb:26:in `validate_each'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.16/lib/active_model/validator.rb:153:in `block in validate'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.16/lib/active_model/validator.rb:150:in `each'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.16/lib/active_model/validator.rb:150:in `validate'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:310:in `_callback_before_1986'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:407:in `_run__3464288744618424855__validate__1974049388273351148__callbacks'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_validate_callbacks'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.16/lib/active_model/validations.rb:228:in `run_validations!'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.16/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:53:in `block in run_validations!'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__3464288744618424855__validation__1974049388273351148__callbacks'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.16/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:53:in `run_validations!'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.16/lib/active_model/validations.rb:195:in `valid?'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/validations.rb:69:in `valid?'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-expectations-2.14.5/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:24:in `handle_matcher'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/memoized_helpers.rb:68:in `should'
 # ./spec/models/setting_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:114:in `instance_eval'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:114:in `block in run'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:254:in `with_around_each_hooks'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:111:in `run'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:390:in `block in run_examples'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `map'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `run_examples'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:371:in `run'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in run'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `map'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block in run'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:58:in `report'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:25:in `run'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:77:in `rescue in run'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

spec_helper.rb: http://pastebin.com/6fzDXnux

Comment: What line does the error refer to?

Comment: it { should be_valid }

Comment: Can you post your model as well?

Comment: The contents of your `spec_helper.rb` would be helpful, as would running with` rspec -b spec/models/settings_spec.rb` to get the full backtrace.

Comment: Have you tried a different validator instead of `uniqueness`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The direct cause for this error is that the class derives from ActiveRecord::Base, and ActiveRecord can't determine the primary key (required by AR for validating uniqueness).  Most likely, this is happening either because you haven't run migrations to create the `settings` table, or you created the `settings` table without a primary key.

The offending line (based on the backtrace provided):

```
relation = relation.and(table[finder_class.primary_key.to_sym].not_eq(record.send(:id))) if record.persisted?
```

Note that `to_sym` is being called on `finder_class.primary_key`.

Comment: A unique key was sufficient. It looks like I forgot to roll back and migrate after adding the unique key to my migration. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction on this, it was driving me crazy!

Comment: I ran into this upgrading from Rails 3.2 to 4.2; declaring a primary_key in the model solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can also solve same by adding below line in your model.

```
self.primary_key = 'id'
```

e.g.

```
Class Person
  self.primary_key = 'id'

end
```